# AWS Cloudformation cloud-init on Amazon Linux AMI fails in util.py

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to have a userdata script in the NAT AMI provided by Amazon. The userdata script never starts execution and when I looked at the logs, I see that there's a failure at

```
Mar 10 21:34:13 cloud-init[2290]: util.py[DEBUG]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 638, in runparts
subp([exe_path], capture=False, shell=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1529, in subp
cmd=args)
ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001']
Exit code: 1
Reason: -
Stdout: ''
Stderr: ''
```

I found in this [related StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818209/user-data-scripts-fails-without-giving-reason) that one user was able to get around it by having `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/sh -e -v` in their `UserData` portion of the template, but the issue does not seem to have a clear solution.

I have tried using just `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/bash -xe` and completely removing this line altogether. I still continue to hit that error.

Has anyone encountered this issue with the Amazon provided NAT AMI before and if so, how do I get around this issue?

My `UserData` looks like this:

```
         "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                                    "#!/bin/bash\n",
                                    "sudo yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

                                    "# Install the files and packages and run the commands from the metadata\n",
                                    "sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --access-key ", { "Ref" : "IAMUserAccessKey" }, " --secret-key ", { "Ref" : "SecretAccessKey" },  
                                    "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                                    "         --resource NAT2 ",
                                    "         --configsets config ",
                                    "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
                            ]]}}
```

Comment: Just a thought, maybe don't run cfn-signal as sudo? It already is running as root

Comment: I tried doing the /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init without the sudo. It did not help. I still see the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue. As Max had suggested, I removed sudo from the cfn-init command. But it did not have the desired effect.

But then, I realized that the environment variables EC2_HOME would not be setup for the sudo. I am doing a bunch of stuff in my configset which uses aws cli and for these to work, the EC2_HOME needs to be setup. So, I went in and removed sudo everywhere in my configset and UserData. So now, my UserData looks like:

```
"UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                                    "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                                    "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

                                    "# Install the files and packages and run the commands from the metadata\n",
                                    "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --access-key ", { "Ref" : "IAMUserAccessKey" }, " --secret-key ", { "Ref" : "SecretAccessKey" },  
                                    "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                                    "         --resource NAT2 ",
                                    "         --configsets config ",
                                    "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
                            ]]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was trying to assign the Apache user to a file but we aren't using apache on this setup so the user didn't exist. This threw a CFN error. It was hard to track down the error but for anyone with this issue I suggest you view the logs here:

```
/var/log/cfn-init.log
```

and look for a traceback with an error message to help you debug.