# Terraform - AWS EC2 Instance - Userdata is available on the device but does not run when I apply the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data, ec2-ami

I've been struggling with this issue for the last few days. I have an instance that is created using a terraform template with userdata that is specified from a template file. The instance uses the Debian Jessie community AMI and I am able to view the user data on the instance through wget. I've tried a copy of the AMI, I've tried using #cloud-boothook, and I've tried putting the userdata script inside the main TF template.

I checked the cloud-init-output.log logs and there is an error that my research indicates to be a problem with environment variables and sudo but I would still expect that the temp file would get created because there is no sudo call preceeding that echo line (from here:[user data scripts fails without giving reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818209/user-data-scripts-fails-without-giving-reason)).

```
 util.py[WARNING]: Running scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
```

Section of my TF template that creates the instance:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami                       = "ami-116d857a"
  instance_type             = "t2.micro"
  source_dest_check         = "False"
  subnet_id                 = "${aws_subnet.public.id}"
  key_name                  = "my-generic-keyname"
  vpc_security_group_ids    = ["${aws_security_group.vpn-sg.id}"]
  user_data                   = "${data.template_file.bootscript.rendered}"
  depends_on                = ["aws_subnet.public"]
}
```

User data contained in the template file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Running user data' > /tmp/user-script-output.txt
sudo apt install strongswan-starter -y
sudo apt install curl -y

# Write secrets file
[cat <<-EOF > /etc/ipsec.secrets
# This file holds shared secrets or RSA private keys for authentication.

# RSA private key for this host, authenticating it to any other host
# which knows the public part.

privateip : PSK "$clientPSK"

EOF
```

Expected Behavior:
When I SSH into the instance, I can view the metadata no problem but the file in /tmp isn't created, curl is not installed, and neither is the strongswan package.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: User data runs as root, drop the `sudo`. Also it might help to look at both `/var/log/cloud-init.log` as well as `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`. You shouldn't need to direct output to `/tmp/user-script-output.txt` because all output should be in the `cloud-init-output.log`.

Comment: I removed sudo and the redirection but I don't see the echo output in var/log/cloud-init-output.log.

I do see this though:

" Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)"