# CloudFormation cfn-init breaking in AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate on Ubuntu base

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use the CloudFormation cfn-init to bootstrap creation of on-demand compute nodes in a cluster built on Ubuntu 18.04. For some reason, cnf-init enter a dead loop. This is the CloudFormation that I am trying to use:

```
Resources:
  InstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - ec2:DescribeTags
                  - cloudformation:DescribeStackResource
                Resource: '*'

  InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref InstanceRole

  LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          default:
            - "basic"
        basic:
          files:
            /home/ubuntu/.emacs:
              content: !Sub |
                ;; ========== Configuring basic Emacs behavior ==========
                ;; Try to auto split vertically all the time
                (setq split-height-threshold nil)
              
                ;; ========== Enable Line and Column Numbering ==========
              
                ;; Show line-number in the mode line
                (line-number-mode 1)
              
                ;; Show column-number in the mode line
                (column-number-mode 1)
              
                ;; Display size in human format in Dired mode
                (setq dired-listing-switches "-alh")
              mode: "000644"
              owner: "ubuntu"
              group: "ubuntu"
          
          packages:
            apt:
              build-essential: []
              emacs-nox: []
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: ami-07a29e5e945228fa1
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: !GetAtt [ InstanceProfile, Arn ]    
        UserData:
          Fn::Base64:
            !Sub |
              #!/bin/bash -x

              # Install the aws CloudFormation Helper Scripts
              apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
              apt-get install -y python2.7 
              update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
              curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
              python get-pip.py
              rm get-pip.py

              pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz

              ## Running init stack
              cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchTemplate --region ${AWS::Region}
      LaunchTemplateName: MyLaunchTemplate
```

Looking at  `/var/log/cfn-init.log` is not really helpfull

```
2020-11-11 17:17:59,172 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
2020-11-11 17:17:59,172 [DEBUG] Describing resource LaunchTemplate in stack LaunchTemplate
2020-11-11 17:17:59,237 [ERROR] Throttling: Rate exceeded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 162, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 234, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request
2020-11-11 17:17:59,237 [DEBUG] Sleeping for 0.143176 seconds before retrying
2020-11-11 17:17:59,381 [DEBUG] Describing resource LaunchTemplate in stack LaunchTemplate
2020-11-11 17:17:59,445 [ERROR] Throttling: Rate exceeded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 162, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 234, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request
2020-11-11 17:17:59,445 [DEBUG] Sleeping for 1.874780 seconds before retrying
2020-11-11 17:18:01,323 [DEBUG] Describing resource LaunchTemplate in stack LaunchTemplate
```

Investigating `/var/log/cloud-init.log`, I can see where it breaks first:

```
(...)
2020-11-11 17:16:57,175 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=False)
2020-11-11 17:21:17,126 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
2020-11-11 17:21:17,129 - util.py[DEBUG]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 878, in runparts
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2164, in subp
    break
cloudinit.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001']
Exit code: 1
Reason: -
Stdout: -
Stderr: -
(...)
```

which is the content of the UserData of the template:

```
$ cat /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001
#!/bin/bash -x

# Install the aws CloudFormation Helper Scripts
apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y python2.7 
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
rm get-pip.py

pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz

## Running init stack
cfn-init -v --stack LaunchTemplate --resource LaunchTemplate --region us-west-2
```

Even thought I set  `cloudformation:DescribeStackResource` in the InstanceRole, running the script as root returns the following error:

```
(...)
Successfully built aws-cfn-bootstrap
+ cfn-init -v --stack LaunchTemplate --resource LaunchTemplate --region us-west-2
AccessDenied: Instance i-0bcf477579987a0e8 is not allowed to call DescribeStackResource for LaunchTemplate
```

This is really strange as when I do the same within a `AWS::EC2::Instance` using the same AMI work just fine. Any idea what's going on here? What am'I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [user data scripts fails without giving reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818209/user-data-scripts-fails-without-giving-reason)

Answer (score 0):

This could be because  `--resource LaunchTemplate` is incorrect. It should the ASG or instance resource that uses the launchtemplate, not the `LaunchTemplate` itself.

Comment: Hmm... Based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html, My understanding of ```--resource``` is from which resource the configset (from the -c parameter) should be taken from... Which is part of why I want to get this figured out... goal here is to recycle configset between different ressources... Anyhow, good start, good thinking...

Comment: @MarcoBlanchette You can't do this. Resource must be logical name of instance or or asg. It will never work with LaunchTemplate nor LaunchConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using the option `--resource LaunchTemplate` is correct. I guess that Marcin was referring to the actual EC2 resource with LaunchConfig (now deprecated) in mind.

The problem is that cross-referencing a LaunchTemplate outside the EC2/ASG stack requires one to set the IAM role explicitly using the option `--role rolename` , see [AWS CloudFormation cfn-init documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html):

> [...] if no credentials are specified, CloudFormation checks for stack
> membership and limits the scope of the call to the stack that the
> instance belongs to.

Hence, the call you are looking for looks like this:

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource LaunchTemplate --region ${AWS::Region} --role ${Ec2InstanceRole} --configsets default
```

Make sure that the referenced IAM::Role (e.g. Ec2InstanceRole) has the following permissions:

- cloudformation:DescribeStacks
- cloudformation:DescribeStackResource
- ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates
- ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions
- ec2:GetLaunchTemplateData