shell script failing with no specific reason in cloud-init
I have a cloud-init script. In that I am trying to run an external script.
The script looks as follows:
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "*** Running fdisk on /dev/sdb"

sed -e 's/\s*\([\+0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' << EOF | fdisk /dev/sdb
o # clear the in memory partition table
n # new partition
p # primary partition
1 # partition number 1
  # default - start at beginning of disk 
  # default - to end of disk 
w # write the partition table
q # and we're done
EOF

echo "*** Finished running fdisk"

This is failing with the following error:
2024-12-10 16:39:38,174 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/create_fdisk.sh'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=False)
2024-12-10 16:39:38,183 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/create_fdisk.sh [1]
2024-12-10 16:39:38,183 - util.py[DEBUG]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/create_fdisk.sh [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 897, in runparts
    subp(prefix + [exe_path], capture=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2084, in subp
    cmd=args)
ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/create_fdisk.sh']
Exit code: 1
Reason: -
Stdout: -
Stderr: -
2024-12-10 16:39:38,185 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/runcmd'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=False)

This is run as part of the following cloud-init script.
users:
  - name: fdaud
    gecos: Feroze Daud
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    groups: sudo
    homedir: /home/fdaud
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAILnxDC4d0EgbmCo/fnBMHxseVoCcYX3q6Y3acnvc4dNy ferozed@dhcp-10-159-145-193.vpn.oracle.com

runcmd:
  - sudo chmod 755 create_fdisk.sh
  - sudo create_fdisk.sh
  # create a fs in the new partition in the block volume
  - sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1
  # create a scratch folder
  - sudo mkdir /scratch
  # mount
  - sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /scratch
  # change ownership
  - sudo chown fdaud:root /scratch

If I run the create_fdisk.sh script manually, it works fine.
I dont know what I am doing wrong.

This (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63674919/26993270) may help to find the error.
